# Something about this 'NOT_FOUND_ERR: Dom exception 8' confuses me

Tags: javascript, exception, dom, appendchild

Well, here I continue, trying to learn this very nice language... So I previously had a very ugly code full of 'document.write()' and more ugly things, and now I am transforming it into a very nice standards compliant code, and I am liking it! But I found a problem where I don't see the logic. Here it goes:

In the html file I have this:

```
<body onload="generatetable(0)">
```

And in the .js file I have this:

```
function generatetable(product) {    
    var tbinfo = document.createElement("table");  //table
    var tbbody = document.createElement("tbody");  //tbody
    var row = document.createElement("tr");     // creates row
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {               // creates 4 cells
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        }

    var tname = arraypro[product].Name;
    cell.appendChild(tname);
```

(I don't paste the rest of the table, because it seems to work fine)

And when running, I get the 'Exception 8' error on the `var tname = arraypro[product].Name` line

But if I do just an

```
alert(arraypro[0].Name);
```

it outputs exactly what it should output, the very right word. How it's possible that the value in `arraypro[product].Name` can be retrieved by an `alert` (if you pass the value of 'product') but not by the `appendChild`?

I am still not very well used to the logic of programming, but I try...

PD: The `arraypro` , where the information is, has been declared as a global value, accessible for everything, in case it matters to know.

Thanks very much for any input here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`appendChild()` expects a DOM-Node, you're passing in a string I believe.

You can change it to:

```
var tname = arraypro[product].Name;
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tname));
```

Comment: Sir, I love you. I just tried it and that was really the problem. I will accept your answer as soon as the system lets me (10 minutes)